# How import android design support library with custom appcompat-v7?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androiddesignsupport, android-appcompat

I use `Android Studio` for my project.
I want to use custom `appcompat-v7` library in my android project.
**Android design support library** has it own appcompat-v7 library.

**`my gradle`**

> compile(':mycustomAppcompat-v7')
>   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

**`My problem`:**
I have two `appcompat-v7` library that come from:

```
1-My custom library.
2-Design support needed.
```

how can i fix it?
thank you

Comment: Why do you need a custom appcompat-v7?

Comment: @kleinsenberg Because i need a right to left Toolbar. https://github.com/arashsammak/RTL-Toolbar-Android-AppCompat

Comment: Do something like this `compile('com.android.support:design:23.2.0'){
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }`

Comment: either what @zgc7009 is suggesting, or try to extract only the classes you need under a new package. Worst case scenario, repackage the library, and use it under a different namespace.

Comment: @kleinsenberg Thank.

Comment: @zgc7009  you can post your answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude specific modules from libraries you compile with gradle. This feature is valuable in a number of specific situations, like when you have conflicting or duplicated modules as in your case. To fix this, you can explicitly determine which modules you would like to exclude from compilation in gradle as follows:

```
compile('com.android.support:design:23.2.0'){ 
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7' 
}
```

This says you want to compile `com.android.support:design:23.2.0` but you want to exclude its `appcompat-v7` module since you are utilizing your custom one.